# How to use structs with 2D Arrays and Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, arrays, struct, 2d

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the same results as the following code, but with a struct.

My goal is to create a dynamically allocated 2D Array initilialized to all zeroes by using the struct but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried numerous things on my own and that i found online, and none of them seem to work.

```
printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &r);
printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
scanf("%d", &c);
int** list = (int**)malloc(r * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0 ; i < r ; i++) {
        list[i] = (int*) malloc(c * sizeof(int));
        for ( x = 0 ; x < c ; x++) {
                list[i][x] = 0;
        }
}
```

My code for the struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_rows;
    int num_cols;
    int** data;
} BinaryMatrix;

BinaryMatrix* ConstructBinaryMatrix(int num_rows,int num_cols);


BinaryMatrix* ConstructBinaryMatrix(int num_rows, int num_cols) {
    if (num_rows <= 0 || num_cols <= 0) {
            printf("Error.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
            int i,x;
            BinaryMatrix* A;
            A->num_rows = num_rows;
            A->num_cols = num_cols;

            A->data = (int**) malloc(A->num_rows * sizeof(int*));

            for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
                    (A->data)[i] = malloc(A->num_cols * sizeof(int*));
                    for (x = 0; x < A->num_cols; x++) {
                            (A->data)[i][x] = 0;
                    }
            }

            return A;
    }
}

BinaryMatrix* M;
printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &num_rows);
printf("Enter the number of cols: ");
scanf("%d", &num_cols);
M = ConstructBinaryMatrix(num_rows, num_cols);
```

The error I am receiving is a Segmentation Fault. And it seems to be happening the moment the first malloc call is done.

I am learning C and need some guidance here. I am coming from Python so all this is new to me. Please help, thank you.

Comment: `BinaryMatrix* A; A->num_rows;`. That is the problem. `A` is an uninitialised variable and must not be dereferenced. You need to `malloc` memory for `A` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryMatrix* A;
A->num_rows = num_rows;
```

This is your problem; you're dereferencing an un-`malloc`'d pointer. You need to first `malloc` a `BinaryMatrix` and assign it to `A` to be able to dereference its fields.

```
BinaryMatrix* A = malloc(sizeof(BinaryMatrix));
```

Comment: Just tried it but it still seems to cause a Segmentation Fault. I swapped the line: BinaryMatrix* A; into BinaryMatrix* A = malloc(sizeof(BinaryMatrix)); like you said.

Comment: i tried your code changing only this line of code (and inserting a main() function of course) and works just fine for me. i can post the code below if it helps...

Comment: You're right, it does work. The segmentation fault I was receiving was coming from somewhere else, not this function. thank you very much to everyone.